# start ul li as specific position from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

this is xml file:-

```
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="m.xsl"?> 
<root>
    <child_1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
        <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
            <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
                <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
                    <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
                        <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
                    </child_10067>
                </child_10066>
                <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
                <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
                <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
                <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
                <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
            </child_4>
            <child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="2">
                <child_4332 entity_id="4332" value="Asia" parent_id="4331">
                    <child_4333 entity_id="4333" value ="India" parent_id="4332">
                        <child_4334 entity_id ="4334" value = "Gujarat" parent_id="4333"/>
                    </child_4333>
                </child_4332>
            </child_4331>
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
</root>
```

here i am using this type of xslt:-

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul> 
      <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*) = 'root'"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">first</xsl:text> </xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this xslt output is:-

- Activities

  - Physical1

    - Cricket

      - One Day
  - Test2
  - Test3
  - Test4
  - Test5
  - Physical

set firsl ul id `id="frist"`

how can its possible using xslt...
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Change your current template:

```
  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul> 
    <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*) = 'root'"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">first</xsl:text> </xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

with this one:

```
  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul> 
      <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*) = 'root'"><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">first</xsl:text> </xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: yes i am using above template but not insert id in ul check i have delete totally stupid code and update new code its help full to see where is the problem in my system i made...